# Prometheus I set the scrape_interval 1d

Tags: java, spring, prometheus

When I set the scrape_interval to be 1d/24h, the first time scrape doesn’t happen after 1d/24h. It seems to be a random time.So how I setting  can make it scrape after 1d/24h?

Comment: How did you set? Add the exact configuration you have used.

Comment: Please provide some more details regarding your configuration and code snippets as well. Also try to be as descriptive as possible.